# PI2 and Ubuntu Core 18 kind of stuck

Tags: pi-2, ubuntu

I just conect my PI2 that I purchased a few years ago. I could not install any of the Raspbian or what was on the micro sd card. So, I downloaded and installed ubuntu-core-18-armhf+raspi2.img.xz. After being bugged with the ssh thing everything seemed ok but it is not doing anything after: 
Personalize your account at https://login.ubuntu.com.

I unpluged and repluged but I always have the following:
Ubuntu Core 18 on 192.xxx.x.xxx (tty1)
The host key fingerprints are:
   RSA    SHA256:  slslsls......
   ECDSA  SHA256:  lslslslsls......
   ED25519 SHA256: ksksksks.....

To login:
    ssh something@192.xxx.....
Personalize your account at https://login.ubuntu.com.

But there is nothing to personalize.

What do you suggest?

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve?

Comment: I suggest to use [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). As official operating system it is best supported. What was wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks Ingo, I finally reformat the micro sd and installed Raspbian stretch after unsuccessfully tried the new NOOBS. Everything seems fine.